# How can I limit an ArcGIS REST Servers layer query to the current map extent on screen in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, contour, arcgis-rest-api

I am trying to connect to an ArcGIS REST Service and retrieve vectors for 2ft Contours. It seems like QGIS asks for all features by default which ends up being too large a request and the request beachballs/times out.

Is there a way either through the Browser > ArcGIS REST Service or Data Source Manager dialog to limit the query to the current map extent?

Even if I use Data Source Manager and check `Only request featuers overlapping the current view extent` it times out or has some kind of issue.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to make this work?

Comment: what is the server url - it may be setup not to accept a limit or extent.

Comment: @Mapperz This is the server I was using: http://52.37.30.30/arcgis/rest/services/PublicViewer/MapServer/28 but it is no longer responding for me (perhaps I was blocked?) and it turns out it wasn't the right server anyways.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to download the data once, and don't care about panning/zooming to non-selected areas, use the **Extract/Clip by extent** tool from the Processing Toolbox.

Select *Browse for Layer ...* under the dropdown:

[image]

Assuming you already have the layer set up as an ArcGIS REST Service, select it from the browser:

[image]

Draw your extent on the map, and hit run.

[image]

Selecting **Clip features to extent** may be worthwhile as contours often extend well outside the area of interest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. Unfortunately the issue I was having was in first downloading the contours. I suspect the server I was using was having issues because it has now become unresponsive.